# How to change one-key Cipher into two-key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

> Assignment 2: Two Keys
>
> Write a decrypt method that has one String parameter named input. This method returns a String that is the encrypted String decrypted using the key1 and key2 associated with this CaesarCipherTwo object. You might want to add more private fields to the class.

Can someone please help me here? I don't have the slightest idea of how to go about writing code for a decrypt method. I think it should have one return statement, where I have two. And what does "associated with CaesarCipherTwo object" mean in terms of how to write the code?

Here's what I have already. Any suggestions are welcome:

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class CaesarCipherTwoKeys {
    private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower2;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper2;
    private int mainKey1;
    private int mainKey2;
    public CaesarCipherTwoKeys(int key1, int key2) {
        alphabetLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        alphabetUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        shiftedAlphabetLower1 = alphabetLower.substring(key1) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key1);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper1 = alphabetUpper.substring(key1) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key1);
        shiftedAlphabetLower2 = alphabetLower.substring(key2) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key2);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper2 = alphabetUpper.substring(key2) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key2);
        mainKey1 = key1;
        mainKey2 = key2;
    }
    public String encrypt(String input) {
        StringBuilder encryptedInput = new StringBuilder(input);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey2);

        for (int index=0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            if (index % 2 == 0 || index == 0) {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc1.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
            else {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc2.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
        }
        return encryptedInput.toString();
    }
    public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey2);
        return oocc1.encrypt(input);
        return oocc2.encrypt(input);

    }
}
```

Here is the OOCC class which is referenced in the above code:

import edu.duke.*;

```
public class OOCaesarCipher {
    private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper;
    private int mainKey;
    public OOCaesarCipher(int key) {
        alphabetLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        alphabetUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        shiftedAlphabetLower = alphabetLower.substring(key) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper = alphabetUpper.substring(key) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key);
        mainKey = key;
    }
    public String encrypt(String input) {
        StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder(input);
        for (int index=0; index < encrypted.length(); index++) {
            Character currChar = encrypted.charAt(index);
            int currentIndex = 0;

            if (Character.isLowerCase(currChar)) {
                currentIndex = alphabetLower.indexOf(currChar);
            }
            else {
                currentIndex = alphabetUpper.indexOf(currChar);
            }

            if (currentIndex != -1 && Character.isLowerCase(currChar)) {
                char newChar = shiftedAlphabetLower.charAt(currentIndex);
                encrypted.setCharAt(index, newChar);
            }
            else if (currentIndex != -1) {
                char newChar = shiftedAlphabetUpper.charAt(currentIndex);
                encrypted.setCharAt(index, newChar);
            }
        }
        return encrypted.toString();
    }
    public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey);
        return oocc.encrypt(input);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code that you have written? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: It has the encryption part alright, but it needs a decryption method for me to finish this assignment.

Comment: What is `OOCaesarCipher`?

Comment: And, there is no reason why your `decrypt` should not work, as Caesar-Decipher against key(i) is same as Caesar-encipher with key(26-i).

Comment: But I have two return statements for decrypt method. Is that feasible?

Comment: I've added the OOCaesarCipher class in the question above.

Comment: Obvs 2 return statements won't work. It will return the first time. Second return statement is useless.

Comment: Also, I don't think there is any use of this `OOCaesarCipher` class either. Can't you just create a driver class (with main), that instantiates `CaesarCipherTwoKeys` and sets the `keys` to encrypt and then again set the `keys` to decrypt and do whatever operation you have to do.

Comment: How would I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: OK, to answer my comment on [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687865/write-a-breakcaesarcipher-program) your two key cipher means alternate letters - that's what the loop at the bottom of your encrypt function is doing. If you just copy that loop into decrypt, the function is exactly the same as encrypt but with the two `26-`s then it should work. Or just copy the whole encrypt function and change the `.encrypt`s in the replace lines to `.decrypt`, but that would do more allocation under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

For your decrypt method, I believe you want to return the original input string. To follow the style of your code, you can actually call the encrypt method from your decrypt method with `26-key` as follows

```java
public String decrypt(String input) {
    mainKey1 = 26-mainKey1;
    mainKey2 = 26-mainKey2;
    String decrypted = CaeserCipherTwoKeys.encrypt(input);
    // To maintain code consistency
    mainKey1 = 26-mainKey1;
    mainKey2 = 26-mainKey2;
```