# Write a BreakCaesarCipher program

Tags: java, encryption

so I have a programming question. I want to be able to create a breakCaesarCipher class that does the following:

1) splitting the encrypted message

2) determining the two decryption keys

3) creating an instance of CaesarCipherTwo with those keys.

4) calling the decrypt method.

I don't know where to begin. I'm confused as to how one might split the encrypted message. In a previous lesson we did it like so:

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class CaesarBreaker2 {
    public int[] countOccurrencesOfLetters(String message) {
        //snippet from lecture
        String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int k=0; k < message.length(); k++) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            int dex = alph.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }
    public int maxIndex(int[] values) {
        int maxDex = 0;
        for (int k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
            if (values[k] > values[maxDex]) {
                maxDex = k;
            }
        }
        return maxDex;
    }
    public String decrypt(String encrypted) {
        CaesarCipher cc = new CaesarCipher();
        int[] freqs = countOccurrencesOfLetters(encrypted);
        int maxDex = maxIndex(freqs);
        int dkey = maxDex - 4;
        if (maxDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - (4-maxDex);
        }
        return cc.encrypt(encrypted,26-dkey);
    }
    public String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
        StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index=start;index < message.length();index += 2) {
            halfString.append(message.charAt(index));
        }
        return halfString.toString();
    }
    public int getKey(String s) {
        int[] letterFreqs = countOccurrencesOfLetters(s);
        int maxDex = maxIndex(letterFreqs);
        int dkey = maxDex - 4;
        if (maxDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - (4-maxDex);
        }
        return 26-dkey;
    }
    public String decryptTwoKeys(String encrypted) {
        String firstHalfEncrypted = halfOfString(encrypted,0);
        String secondHalfEncrypted = halfOfString(encrypted,1);
        int firstHalfKey = getKey(firstHalfEncrypted);
        int secondHalfKey = getKey(secondHalfEncrypted);
        CaesarCipherTwo ccT = new CaesarCipherTwo();

        System.out.println("First key:\t" + firstHalfKey + "\nSecond key:\t"
                            + secondHalfKey);

        return ccT.encryptTwoKeys(encrypted,firstHalfKey,secondHalfKey);
    }
    public void testDecrypt() {
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource();
        String encrypted = fileResource.asString();
        System.out.println("Encrypted message:\n" + encrypted);
        System.out.println("\nDecrypted message:\n" + decryptTwoKeys(encrypted));

        String encrypted2 = "Aal uttx hm aal Qtct Fhljha pl Wbdl. Pvxvxlx!";
        System.out.println("Encrypted message:\n" + encrypted2);
        System.out.println("\nDecrypted message:\n" + decryptTwoKeys(encrypted2));
    }
}
```

but I don't understand how to convert this code so it will work in this new class called TestCaesarCipherTwo. Here is the code for TestCaesarCipherTwo:

```
import edu.duke.*;


public class TestCaesarCipherTwo {
   public int[] countOccurrencesOfLetters(String message) {
        //snippet from lecture
        String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int k=0; k < message.length(); k++) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            int dex = alph.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }
    public int maxIndex(int[] values) {
        int maxDex = 0;
        for (int k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
            if (values[k] > values[maxDex]) {
                maxDex = k;
            }
        }
        return maxDex;
   }

   public String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
        StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index=start;index < message.length();index += 2) {
            halfString.append(message.charAt(index));
        }
        return halfString.toString();

   }
      public void simpleTests() {
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource();
        String fileAsString = fileResource.asString();
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(17, 3);
        String encrypted = cctk.encrypt(fileAsString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted string:\n"+encrypted);
        String decrypted = cctk.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted string:\n"+decrypted);

        String blindDecrypted = breakCaesarCipher(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted string using breakCaesarCipher():\n"+blindDecrypted);
   }
    public String breakCaesarCipher(String input) {
        int[] freqs = countOccurrencesOfLetters(input);
        int freqDex = maxIndex(freqs);
        int dkey = freqDex - 4;
        if (freqDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - (4-freqDex);
        }
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey);
        return cctk.decrypt(input);
   }
}
```

WARNING: I also have a constructor error on this line CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey); stating CaesarCipherTwoKeys in class CaesarCipherTwoKeys cannot be applied to given types; required int,int; found int....

Can anyone show me how to change my code so that my breakCaesarCipher method splits the encrypted message, determines the two decryption keys used to encrypt the message, create an instance of CaesarCipherTwo with those two keys, and call the decrypt method? Any suggestions are welcome. Please let me know if you want more details into the nature of this problem.

Comment: How does a two keys Caesar cipher work: just split the string in the middle like you have here? Or alternate letters? Either way, can't you just feed the separate halves of the string into your breakCipher function and have that return the two decryption keys? Your decryption approach is just to assume that E is the most frequent letter, which isn't brilliant but it looks like that's the one you were given - in particular I'm not sure that can be obviously extended to analysing both halves at once as e.g. a letter frequency table approach could.

Comment: And I'm afraid you're unlikely to get someone to do your assignment for you, sorry. If you have a specific question we can answer it, but as it stands I'm not clear how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Sorry to clarify this: "can't you just feed the separate halves of the string into your breakCipher function and have that return the two decryption keys" - I meant call the function twice, once with each half of the string.

Comment: One final thought: if (as it sounds) all you need is the decrypted output, you can make do with your current break method as-is. Split the input into two halves, break each half and then interleave them back together to get the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string with CaesarCipherBreaker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688725/splitting-a-string-with-caesarcipherbreaker)

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me how this would look like in code?

Comment: Does my current break method do as you said above?

Comment: If you changed it to construct an OOCaesarCipher rather than a CipherTwoKeys it would probably break a single string, yes. (Assuming that choosing the most frequent letter = 'E' is good enough to break it, that is.)

Comment: Are we talking about this line here?: `CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey);
        return cctk.decrypt(input);`

Comment: Yes, that's the one. But then you'd need to stitch it together again. If you want the simplest change to your code you should probably go with Hermann's answer.