# Splitting a string with CaesarCipherBreaker

Tags: java, encryption

How would I add code to this example for creating a CaesarCipherBreaker method that splits the encrypted message by two keys. So far I have this much written down:

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class TestCaesarCipherTwo {
   public int[] countOccurrencesOfLetters(String message) {
        //snippet from lecture
        String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int k=0; k < message.length(); k++) {
            char ch = Character.toLowerCase(message.charAt(k));
            int dex = alph.indexOf(ch);
            if (dex != -1) {
                counts[dex] += 1;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }
    public int maxIndex(int[] values) {
        int maxDex = 0;
        for (int k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
            if (values[k] > values[maxDex]) {
                maxDex = k;
            }
        }
        return maxDex;
   }

   public String halfOfString(String message, int start) {
        StringBuilder halfString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index=start;index < message.length();index += 2) {
            halfString.append(message.charAt(index));
        }
        return halfString.toString();

   }
      public void simpleTests() {
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource();
        String fileAsString = fileResource.asString();
        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(17, 3);
        String encrypted = cctk.encrypt(fileAsString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted string:\n"+encrypted);
        String decrypted = cctk.decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted string:\n"+decrypted);

        String blindDecrypted = breakCaesarCipher(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted string using breakCaesarCipher():\n"+blindDecrypted);
   }
    public String breakCaesarCipher(String input) {
        int[] freqs = countOccurrencesOfLetters(input);
        int freqDex = maxIndex(freqs);
        int dkey = freqDex - 4;
        if (freqDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - (4-freqDex);
        }

        CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey);
        return cctk.decrypt(input);
   }
}
```

WARNING: I also have a constructor error on this line `CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey);` stating `CaesarCipherTwoKeys in class CaesarCipherTwoKeys cannot be applied to given types; required int,int; found int...`.

The breakCaesarCipher method I have now only figures out **one** key, not two. How should I go about writing a method that splits an encrypted string, figuring out two keys used for decryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your Code correctly, you could just call your `halfOfString` (two times) to get the two parts of the ciphertext and then use your usual approach to breaking a Ceaser-Cipher on both parts separately.

Your error seems to result from the fact that the two-key-encryption expects (unsurprisingly) two keys. You should give them both to the constructor.

```
public String breakCaesarCipher(String input) {
    String in_0 = halfOfString(input, 0);
    String in_1 = halfOfString(input, 1);
    // Find first key
    // Determine character frequencies in ciphertext
    int[] freqs_0 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_0);
    // Get the most common character
    int freqDex_0 = maxIndex(freqs_0);
    // Calculate key such that 'E' would be mapped to the most common ciphertext character
    // since 'E' is expected to be the most common plaintext character
    int dkey_0 = freqDex_0 - 4;
    // Make sure our key is non-negative
    if (dkey_0 < 0) {
        dkey_0 = dkey_0+26;
    }
    // Find second key
    int[] freqs_1 = countOccurrencesOfLetters(in_1);
    int freqDex_1 = maxIndex(freqs_1);
    int dkey_1 = freqDex_1 - 4;
    if (freqDex_1 < 4) {
        dkey_1 = dkey_1+26;
    }

    CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey_0, dkey_1);
    return cctk.decrypt(input);
}
```

Comment: I have added Code. If this answers your question, please accept the answer. Otherwise detail your problems further.

Comment: Should I delete the rest of the code that I used to have for my break method? For example: `int[] freqs = countOccurrencesOfLetters(input);
        int freqDex = maxIndex(freqs);
        int dkey = freqDex - 4;
        if (freqDex < 4) {
            dkey = 26 - (4-freqDex);
        }`

Comment: No, this is the part you write instead of my comment. This was how you got a single key, so you do his two times now, but with `in_0`, `in_1` instead of `input` and `dkey_0`, dkey_1` instead of `dkey`.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, I keep the old break method but just add `String in_0 = halfOfString(input, 0);
    String in_1 = halfOfString(input, 1);
    // Find keys as before x2

    CaesarCipherTwoKeys cctk = new CaesarCipherTwoKeys(dkey_0, dkey_1);
    return cctk.decrypt(input);`?

Comment: If you can could you change your code in your answer. I think that would help clarify things better.

Comment: No, you replace `// Find keys as before x2` in my code with the actual attempts to find the keys. You already know how to do this if you understand your own code. Otherwise I refuse to help you with this.

Comment: Let's do this in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100200/questions-34688725

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that limit: 
Did you write this code yourself?
If so, explain to me, line by line, what you think your code does.

Comment: First line: imports edu.duke library. Second line:  declares class TestCaesarCipherTwo. Third line: declares public int value for the number of times a letter appears...

Comment: Fourth line: creates a string called alph, containing alphabet. Fifth line: sets counts to 26.

Comment: Sorry, only the `breakCaesarCipher` please. Also, I have to sleep now, but I'll be back in a few hours to look at what you've written. However, take your time.

Comment: And `sets a to b` is *reading* the line in another language. An explanation would be “We set `a` to the length of the list, to have quick access to relative positions.” Explain your *intentions* and *concepts*. Give me the *Why?* and not the *What?*.

Comment: Sixth line: intialize k as 0, k is less than message length, counter adds how many times k appears. Seventh line: ch equals lowercase character at kth position in the message.

Comment: Breaker First line: calls integer frequencies of how many times a letter is found. Second line: finds the most common letter frequency. The last three lines I don't understand. I was given this bit from an example in our Coursera class.

Comment: Specifically the second line is 'find the letter with the most common frequency'. The one after that sets the decryption key to (most frequent letter - 4), i.e. map the letter with the most common frequency to be 'E' (where 'E' - 'A' = 4) in the output. IMO the if statement would be clearer as `if (dkey < 0) { dkey += 26; }` - it's making sure that the key we've just calculated is in the range 0 to 25.

Comment: So what you now need to do is repeat those steps (count letters, find one with most common frequency, dkey = most common - 4, correct negative dkey) with for each of in_0 and in_1, and save the dkeys as dkey_0 and dkey_1. (For simplicity use different intermediate variable names for each case, although you could also break that out into a new function.) Put this code in Hermann's answer in place of the 'Find keys as before x2' comment.

Comment: You always should try to understand the code you're given first. Modifying it without understanding is (unsurprisingly) hard or impossible. You should have asked about that in your class. Or, if impossible, search the Web. And if nothing turns up, ask here, _before_ you ask questions that require this understanding.